# Visual studio cannot find reference System.ObjectMo HelloWorld.Android del

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I am completely new to visual studio and just installed it today.
I am just trying out my helloworld app but it cannot find a reference.
System.ObjectMo HelloWorld.Android del
It cannot find this reference, how can I add this reference so i can start the emulator and get back to learning.

Comment: Is it a PCL project?

Comment: You could removed the reference entirely since you just start learning `Xamarin.Android`.